# why UINavigationBar color change after return form aAnother viewController with diferente color

Tags: ios, swift

i have my base View controller with it´s embbed navigation controller so i set ist collor , when segue are executed the new view has it owns navigationbar color and it changes to it but after return to the back view this view takes the color from the previuos one. 
i´m setting the color of the navigationbar like this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = appDelegate.verde
}
```

its a defined color in the Appdelegate to be green color in the 
in the next one i change in the color of the navigationbar the same way as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the color of the `UINavigationBar` and it remains changed unless you explicitly change it to something else. `UINavigationBar` does not depend on `viewControllers` - it's above them.

In order to have different color for each `viewController` when navigating between them back and forth, change `UINavigationBar`'s color in `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = appDelegate.verde
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `viewDidLoad` you may put this code in `viewWillAppear`. This will be invoked each time the view is about to be presented so it will override any color changes for other views.